# Error parse multiples objects Property 'length' does not exist

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I have the following definition for a function that is called by an event.

```
    forceUpdateLiveLocation: Returns Promise<false | true | LiveLocationChangedEvent[]>
     const forcedLiveLocation = await client.forceUpdateLiveLocation( message.from );
     console.log(forcedLiveLocation[0]);
```

works but this returns only the first object

```
[{
  lat: -2.510491,
  lng: -44.220796
}]
```

when I have several events he builds objects like this:

```
[ {
  lat: -2.510491,
  lng: -44.220796
},{
  lat: -2343434,
  lng: -443434343
}];
```

so I try to do a `for` to the objects but i have a error.

```
for(var i = 0; i < forcedLiveLocation.length; i++){
    console.log(forcedLiveLocation[i].lat.toString());   
}
```

**Error:**

> Property 'length' does not exist on type 'boolean | LiveLocationChangedEvent[]'.
>     Property 'length' does not exist on type 'false'.

Comment: try to print `console.log(forcedLiveLocation);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to what i'm guessing is the documentation at https://open-wa.github.io/wa-automate-nodejs/classes/client.html#forceupdatelivelocation:

> A list of participants in the chat who have their live location on. If
>   the chat does not exist, or the chat does not have any contacts
>   actively sharing their live locations, it will return false. If it's a
>   chat with a single contact, there will be only 1 value in the array if
>   the contact has their livelocation on. Please note. This should only
>   be called once every 30 or so seconds. This forces the phone to grab
>   the latest live location data for the number. This can be used in
>   conjunction with onLiveLocation (this will trigger onLiveLocation).

So, sometimes you get your array of events and sometimes you don't. You'll need to respond accordingly to the different cases.

```
if (Array.isArray(forcedLiveLocation)){ 
    for(var i = 0; i < forcedLiveLocation.length; i++){
        console.log(forcedLiveLocation[i].lat.toString());   
    }
} else {
    // do something else
}
```

Comment: perfect it even solved a problem i was having with setInterval too, thanks

Answer (score 0):

The promise supposed to return one of these types `bool` or `LiveLocationChangedEvent[]` so you need to handle the type of the `forceUpdateLiveLocation` function.

```
if(typeof forcedLiveLocation !== "boolean") // then do what ever you want
```

logging the result works because `console.log` has nothing to do with returned type